# Cosine Similarity - Drawbacks as Recommendation Engine?

Tags: neo4j, machine-learning, knn, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I have seen Cosine Similarity used in K-Nearest Neighbor algorithms to generate recommendations based on user preferences. In these models, user ratings for a given product are treated as vectors, and then similarity between two users is determined by the Cosine Similarity between the two vectors. (e.g. http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8173017)

**My Question is this:**
Can anybody explain how recommendation engines using Cosine Similarity account for parallel user preferences? **It seems to me that two users can have completely polar rating preferences and yet generate a Cosine Similarity of 1 if they have parallel (but different) preferences.** For example, if one user rates 5 movies as being 1 out of 10 stars, and another user rates the same 5 movies as being 10 out of 10 stars, their Cosine Similarity would be 1 (which in my mind, seems like an inaccurate measure of user similarities).

[image: cosine similarity]

Example of the issue:
If we are measuring the user preferences of two users, and we’re measuring their preferences for 3 products, we can store their preferences as two vectors:

a =(1,1,1) and b=(10,10,10)

Then we can use cosine similarity to measure how similar they are to each other. But in this instance, their cosine similarity would be 1, even though they represent polar opposite user preferences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known that the vanilla cosine similarity has one important [drawback](http://files.grouplens.org/papers/www10_sarwar.pdf)–the difference in rating scale between different users are not taken into account.

The adjusted cosine similarity offsets this drawback by subtracting the corresponding user average from each co-rated pair. Formally, the similarity between items i and j using this
scheme is given by
[image]

Here `R¯u` is the average of the u-th user’s ratings.

In your example, after preprocessing, both a and b becomes

```
(0,0,0). // We cannot calculate the cosine similarity since the normalizer is 0.
```

this is rare in reality (also if a user consistently rate the same score to every item, it makes no contribution to understand either the user or the items).

Suppose we add one other preference score in each user's preference vector to make the similarity calculable.

```
a = (1,1,1,2)
b = (10,10,10,8)
a1 = (1,2,2,1)   // a user that has similar preference to a
b1 = (9,8,9,10)  // another user that has similar preference to b
norm_a = a - mean(a) = [-0.25000  -0.25000  -0.25000   0.75000]
norm_b = b - mean(b) = [0.50000   0.50000   0.50000  -1.50000]
norm_a1 = [-0.50000  0.50000  0.50000 -0.50000]
norm_b1 = [0  -1   0   1]

sim(a,b) = norm_a*norm_b / (sqrt(sum(norm_a.^2)) * sqrt(sum(norm_b.^2))) = -1
```

Similarly:

```
sim(a,a1) = 0.866
sim(b,b1) = -0.82
```

Comment: This was exactly the explanation I was looking for, thanks a lot. 
When I run the numbers I don't get the same values as you though...for sim(a,b) I get a similarity of -1. Likewise, for sim(a,a1) I get a similarity of -.58.

Comment: @greeness Isn't this the same as the Pearson correlation coefficient? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, people usually talk about cosine similarity in terms of vector angles, but it can be loosely thought of as a correlation, provided that you think of the vectors as paired samples.